# Xamarin.iOS - ERROR ITMS-90502: Invalid Bundle

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I developed a Xamarin.Forms app for a client who is now trying to upload it to the Apple App Store but they're getting the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90503: "Invalid Bundle. Apps that have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist must only contain the arm64 slice."

My Info.plist contains the following blocks:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>arm64</string>
</array>
```

In my iOS Options menu in the iOS Build section, "Supported architectures" is set to "ARM64", "Enable device specific-builds" is unchecked, "Strip native debug symbols" is unchecked.

I can't figure out what I can change to fix this.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @Land I completely removed `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` from Info.plist  and set `Supported architectures` in the iOS project options to `ARMv7 + ARM64`. That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Fine, I think you just want your app to run only in the 64 bits device at first.  So I recommend you to set arm64.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS Build, we should change the **Configuration** to Release and **Platform** to iPhone firstly and then make sure the **Supported Architectures** is arm64. Moreover, please check whether your project contains code or SDK that only supports 32 bits. Also, we should use release setting to build the project and retrieve the ipa file.

You can refer to this:

[image]